# Blurring background image not text on hover

Tags: html, css, image, hover, blur

Hello dear developers,

Iam having a problem by coding my Post grid. I want to blur the background image on hovering. But my text (in the same div is also blurring). Do you have a solution for this? Or isnt there an other way, without using this picture in a new div in the container. Want to keep it as background-image

The posts php:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="article" style="background-image: url(<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>);" onclick="self.location.href='<?php echo get_permalink( $leavename = false ); ?>'">
                <div class="post_info">
                    <span class="post_cat"><?php the_category(' ') ?></span>
                    <h2 class="post_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <span class="post_date"><?php the_time('d.m.Y') ?></span>
                </div>

            <!-- .article --></div>
```

The css:

```
.article:hover {
-webkit-filter: blur(2px);
}
.article {
margin-top: 15px;
position: relative;
height: 229px;
margin-left: 15px;
margin-right: 15px;
float: left;
width: 25%;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Thank you for helping me out, ExotiQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can't** blur a background image, but you can blur any elements or pseudo-elements

I would go on and give a solution to your problem, but this one sums it up pretty good.
[Check out this awnser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39122489/2880747)

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: Thank you mate. After a bit of trying, I just moved the Thumbnail to div inside. And scaled it on the same size. But until now im not very used to postition att. But thank you for your solution=D

Comment: Glad i could help :)!